# Codeigniter application not working on app engine, showing 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I've uploaded my web app to app engine, it's constantly showing 404. I've tried these configs.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

| `'AUTO'`          Default - auto detects
| `'PATH_INFO'`         Uses the PATH_INFO
| `'QUERY_STRING'`  Uses the QUERY_STRING
| `'REQUEST_URI'`   Uses the REQUEST_URI
| `'ORIG_PATH_INFO'`    Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO

I've tried all the options.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; 

$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

my app.yaml

```
application: xxxxxxxx
version: x
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Does it work without .htaccess and with using index.php in your urls?

Comment: I've not tried that. I don't want index.php in my urls

Comment: I asked just to see if the problem is in the htaccess, or in the server setup

Comment: solved, just

application: xxxxxxxx
version: x
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: index.php

Comment: I have tried url: .* and /.* but nothing works. My index.php script simply isn't running. It shows as a 500 server response. Any ideas?

Comment: @MrPablo, have a look at this https://github.com/edwardmp/CodeIgniter-AppEngine

Comment: Turns out my issue was due to App Engine not allow the use of extended controllers. I had to combined my custom controllers into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Following settings works for me on WAMP Sever with fresh codeigniter v2.1.4 setup.

**CONFIG**

```
$config['base_url']     = '';  
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /Codeigniter2.1.4/

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: AppEngine does not/can not use htaccess files, this is therefore not a helpful answer.